# Java Connection

Tags: java

I have this server/client TCP. The server is run off my desktop. And the client is an applet over at http://example.com/new/ (You won't get to it because it will not load...) It WILL load for me but not anyone else.

The port is 24556 and the host is localhost but I DID portforward the port on my linksys admin page so people SHOULD connect. It works for me (obviously) because the server prints out the movement I go... but the applet won't even load for anyone else.... what's the deal?

Comment: What do they get instead of the applet?

Comment: It loads, I just cannot move. I see a maze and a mace, nothing else. 1/2 the border is green pattern and 1/2 is red pattern

Comment: OK so it loads well I just had my server down.. I will have it up for another 1hr 30mins or so starting now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is the applet connecting to localhost or to the ip of your router?

Comment: erm the socket is connecting to localhost

Comment: If the socket is connecting to 'localhost' won't it try connecting to the machine of the person running the applet, not your desktop?

Or am I missing something?

Answer (score 0):

I got the applet to load. Not sure why...I can't move around though.

This might have something to do with self signed content. And browsers defaulting to not let users run things. I know I've run into that problem before.

Is your computer set up with a static ip? Make sure the router points to that computer, or it'll never connect.

I wrote up a chat client in Java, see it here: http://code.google.com/p/phroxchat, feel free to use it to check if your port forwarding is setup properly.

Comment: How do i check if its a static IP or not?

Comment: The reason you couldn't move is because I did not have the server up.  I'll put it up now... try now :)

Comment: You'll have to google for how to check if it's static. But if you have to ask my guess is that it isn't.

Comment: Ok, doesn't look like the client is connecting on the right port. It's trying to open 25566, and not 24556. And the client is chocking because the socket connection is probably blocking before the GUI and everything else can start up properly. :)

Comment: Actually the port I typed in this question was a made up because I was too lazy to check. Here is the real port: 25566

Hehe sorry